# skip callback in inherited model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, abstract-class

Is there a method like `ActionController::Base#skip_before_filter` for ActiveRecord callbacks like `after_create`? I have a few classes that behave similarly, and to reduce code repetition I created an abstract class. The abstraction contains relation information, validation and an `after_create` callback that creates a new message. `Message` implements this abstractions, so saving the message causes an stack overflow.

Can I remove a callback from a model?

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    after_create :notify

    def notify
        Message.create
    end
end

class Message < Parent
    # skip after_create :notify
end

class Child < Parent
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Message < Parent
  skip_callback :create, :after, :notify
end
```

Check [Rails Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_callback) for details